# JS: I can't get the inner HTML of elements with a specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a calculator out of javascript to work on my skills. I've added the class `num` to all of my buttons that have a number.

I'm trying to display to display the `innerHTML` of those buttons in the console when I click them with this code:

```
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
num.addEventListener('click', getNum);

function getNum(){
    console.log(num.innerHTML);
}

getNum();
```

However all I get is

> num.addEventListener is not a function.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/teenicarus/pen/wrEzwd

what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: getElementsByClassName - note "elementS" there - this is plural form. This means you do not get one or null, but you get 0...n items. Which leads us to result, that function is returning array (Or NodeList exactly), not one item. And arrays cannot listen to events :-)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName`  returns an array of the elements or tags which have the same class name. So be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution you can plug directly in your codepen:

```
var nums = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
[].forEach.call(nums, num => num.addEventListener('click', numClick));

function numClick(){
    // adding + turns the text into an actual number
    console.log(+this.innerHTML);
}
```

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), to iterate over it you can pass it to `[].forEach.call()` like I showed above.

I also renamed the handler to `numClick`, since it doesn't "get" the number. And added `+`, which is a nice shortcut to turn text into a number (otherwise, adding two numbers would yield unexpected results, like `"1" + "2" => "12"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the code like below. `getElementsByClassName` returns collection of elements. Loop through the elements and add `click` event listener. In `getNum`, you can use `this` to get access to the button clicked.

```
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('num');

for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i].addEventListener('click', getNum);
}

function getNum(){
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

You can also use `Array forEach` like the following:

```
[].forEach.call(num, function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', getNum);
})
```

Comment: Makes sense. Can it be done use forEach? Just wondering. If yes: will it be better?

Comment: Great! Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. If you want to get single element assign it an `id` attribute and use `getElementById`. This way you can use `addEventListener` function

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged Jquery to your question I suppose that you are able to use Jquery as well. You can grab the clicked element's class and referance it with '`this'` to get its text.

```
    $('.num').click(function(){
      var x = $(this).text();
      console.log(x);
    });
```

This is a working example you can check the console.log **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=40e0d9eae8c5d47ab5c1b0ac0083e1d8)**

Answer (score 0):

The `.getElementsByClassName` returns not an element, but a collection of them.
You can access elements using `.getElementsByClassName(num)[element's sequential number]`, or better use id's and getElementById method.

Comment: You mean like writing out 10 separate but almost identical commands? That's not really good advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code for your desired output.just copy and try:

```
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
//num.addEventListener('click', getNum);
for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
   num[i].addEventListener('click', getNum);
}
function getNum(){

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+=this.innerHTML; 
    console.log('value:'+this.innerHTML);
}

//getNum();
```